# Why do valid regular expression for password in HTML5 pattern attribute is not working?

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, regex, html

My requirement is:

- One uppercase character,
- One lowercase character,
- One special character,
- One digit,
- Minimum 8 characters,
- Max 15 characters.

My regular expression is:

```
^(?=.*[0-9])(?=.*[a-zA-Z])(?=.*[A-Z])(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[!@#$%^&*]).{8,15}$
```

It accepts all the characters, except `$`,`*` ,`^`.

```
= f.password_field: password, placeholder: "Password",:required=>'true',:class => "form-control password_text form-control",pattern:",:title=>'Min 8letters, one uppercase, lowercase letter, onedigit, one specialcharacter',:onchange => "form.confirm_pwd.pattern = this.value;"

= f.password_field: password_confirmation, placeholder: "Password",:class => "form-control form-control password_text",:required=>'true',title:"Please enter the same Password as above",:name=>'confirm_pwd'
```

When I include `$` and submit,`*` and `^` it shows **"Enter the same password as above"** in the confirmation password field. If I include `#` or other special character it is working good.

Comment: I guess you should use `:pattern => /\A(?=.*[0-9])(?=.*[A-Z])(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[!@#$%^&*]).{8,15}\z/`

Comment: Please format the source code using backticks ( ` ), or by indenting by 4 spaces and adding 2 new lines between the code and text

Comment: It is important to format the questions right, or you will get answers that just copy your initial pattern.

Comment: I suspect there are issues with 1) anchors (on the Ruby side, the `\A` and `\z` must be used, and in the HTML5 pattern, the `^` and `$` make no difference as the pattern is anchored by default, 2) and if the first one is not really an issue in this scenario, there might be some issue with how the symbols are parsed, and you may try passing them as `\x24\x2A\x5E` instead of `$*^`. AND if you define the pattern as a string literal, use `'` (single quotes).

Comment: Thanks for your replies, but nothing works for me. When i use \A and \z shows  'Invalid escape' error, if i remove this, it shows 'Please match the format requested'.  Please help me to resolve this.

Comment: You might want `:multiline => true`

Answer (score 0):

```
:onchange => "form.confirm_pwd.pattern =~ this.value;"
```